# Does Tinylog work with pool connections?

Tags: java, logging, tinylog

Does Someone know if Tinylog works with a pool connections when it is used in tomcat?

I have not found the documentation related with this ([Here](http://www.tinylog.org/support)). could someone tell me the link to read it.

if Tinylog does not have this option, what other api will have it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool and you have registered your database connection as a resource as described in the [official Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), tinylog works with pool connections. You just have to use your resource name as data source URL (see [tinylog manual](http://www.tinylog.org/configuration#JdbcWriter)).

Example Tomcat resource:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

tinylog configuration:

```
tinylog.writer = jdbc
tinylog.writer.url = java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB
```